# RefetchEvents fullcalendar from single event source

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

Am working in fullcalandar jquery plugin,but now i stuck with refetching calendar.
I have two event sources , and i have made custom refresh button on calendar headar. I want to do refetch events only from second event source whenever user hits refresh button.

Is there any way to pass paramater in fullcalendar refetchEvents and do refetch from single event source.

```
events: function(start, end, timezone,callback) {
            $.ajax({
                url:  //FIRST EVENT SOURCE
                dataType: 'json',

                success: function(response) {
                    //attaching the response to the calendar
          }

          $.ajax({
                url:  // SECOND EVENT SOURCE
                dataType: 'json',

                success: function(response) {
                    //attaching response to calendar
                 }
             });
       }
```

Whenever user clicks on custom Refresh button , am doing `$("#calendar").fullcalendar('refetchEvents');` -- this will refetch whole calendar (first + second event source)

What i expect to do is , i want to do refetch only for second event source.

Comment: You should try with this option. 1. Destroy the calendar 2. Recreate the calender.   Or you can go with 1. Refresh the calander.

Comment: e.g $("#cal").fullCalendar( 'refresh' );

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. if you do refresh,that will do refresh from two event sources . Correct me if am wrong. I want to do refresh for single event source.

Comment: What code you try so far?

Comment: If you have only two events in calendar then is there any problem to fetch both event again and display over there?

Comment: No i didn't face any problems on refetchig entire calendar , but facing performance issue.

Comment: It is now possible since today's version 2.8.0. Use refetchEventSources with a source id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: version 2.8.0 was released today and it supports fetching a single event source. My answer below is for older versions.

Am I correct that you don't want to refresh the first source, but you still need to keep the events from the first source on the screen? Then just leave them in a temporary cache. Then, use a global var to check that the user clicked Refresh.

```
var g_FirstSourceEventsCache = null;
var g_IsRefreshClicked = false;

events: function(start, end, timezone,callback) {

          if (g_IsRefreshClicked)   {
             //do not reload from server, load from cache
             callback(g_FirstSourceEventsCache);
             g_IsRefreshClicked = false;
          } else {
            $.ajax({
                url:  //FIRST EVENT SOURCE
                dataType: 'json',

                success: function(response) {
                    //attaching the response to the calendar

                    //save to cache
                    g_FirstSourceEventsCache = myFirstSourceEventsThatIPassedToCallback;
            }
          }

          //second source is always refreshed
          $.ajax({
                url:  // SECOND EVENT SOURCE
                dataType: 'json',

                success: function(response) {
                    //attaching response to calendar
                 }
             });
       }
```